# How to dump utf8 from octal ISO-8859-1 in C

Tags: c, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to output the right character in utf8 given the following octal sequence `\303\255` and `\346\234\254`, but I don't get the correct output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int encode(char *buf, unsigned char ch){
    if(ch < 0x80) {
        *buf++ = (char)ch;
        return 1;
    }
    if(ch < 0x800) {
        *buf++ = (ch >> 6) | 0xC0;
        *buf++ = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        return 2;
    }
    if(ch < 0x10000) {
        *buf++ = (ch >> 12) | 0xE0;
        *buf++ = ((ch >> 6) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        *buf++ = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        return 3;
    }
    if(ch < 0x110000) {
        *buf++ = (ch >> 18) | 0xF0;
        *buf++ = ((ch >> 12) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        *buf++ = ((ch >> 6) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        *buf++ = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        return 4;
    }
    return 0;
}

void output (char *str) {
    char *buffer = calloc(8, sizeof(char));
    int n = 0;
    while(*str) {
        n = encode(buffer + n, *str++);
    }   
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    free (buffer);
}

int main() {
    char *str1 = "\303\255";
    char *str2 = "\346\234\254";
    output(str1);
    output(str2);   

    return 0;
}
```

**Outputs**: `Ã­` & `æ¬` instead of `í` & `本`

Comment: I think your program is doing the right thing (but i haven't checked the code).

If i look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 i see that `\303` = 195 (dez) which is a `Ã­` and a soft hyphen (which is not printed).

Or do you mean that `\303\255` should already be a UTF-8 character? This tool http://unicodelookup.com/#0303%200255/1 tells me that what you got is also correct.

Comment: The input I'm getting is `\303\255` which is the sequence for `í`. Inputting `í` into this [tool](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/octal/) also outputs `\303\255`.

Comment: That tool does not tell you what encoding the input text is using. It could be ISO 8859-15, latin1, or any other.

Comment: @RedX is there a way to determine the encoding?

Comment: Ok, sorry i was mistaken. I confused two things. That tool is fine.

Comment: @PeteDarrow, if you want some good reading, try to download the iso-10646 documents describing the full set of unicode characters.  Finally I don't actually know if you want to output UTF-8 (this is what the question says) to input iso-8859-1 (this also) or the reverse.  The full iso-8859-1 can be converted to characters in the UTF charset, but the opposite is not true, as noneuropean characters have no place in iso-8859-1.  What do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code sequence you use is already UTF-8

```
/* Both of these are already UTF-8 chars. */
char *str1 = "\303\255";
char *str2 = "\346\234\254";
```

So your encode function is trying to encode an already encoded UTF-8 which should not work.

When i print these sequences in my UTF-8 enabled terminal i see what you are expecting to see:

```sh
$ printf "%s\n" $'\303\255'
í
$ printf "%s\n" $'\346\234\254'
本
```

So maybe you need to rethink what you are trying to accomplish and post a new question if you have new problems there.

Comment: the encoding is already UTF  (the mapping between iso-8859-1 and UTF is the identity mapping), utf-8 is an encoding of UTF characters into eight bit bytes.  UTF and utf-8 are different things.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pity, but you cannot compare a `char` value (being it `signed` or `unsigned`) with values over `0x100`.  You are missing something if you try to convert one byte (iso-8859-1) values to utf-8.  The iso-8859-1 characters have the same code values as their UTF counterparts, so the conversion is fairly straightforward, as will be shown below.

First of all, all the iso-8859-1 characters are the same as their UTF counterparts, so the first transformation is the identity:  We convert each value in iso-8859-1 to the same value in UTF (look that when I say UTF y mean the UTF code for that character, without using any codification, as when I say UTF-8, which is actually an encoding of UTF in eight bit bytes)

UTF values in the range `0x80...0xff` must be encoded *with two bytes*, the first byte using bits 7 and 6 with pattern `110000xx` being `xx` the two most significant bits of the input code, and followed by a second byte with `10xxxxxx` being `xxxxxx` the six least significant bits (bits 5 to 0) of the input code.  For UTF values in the range `0x00...0x7f` you encode them with just the same byte as the UTF code.

The following function does preciselly this:

```
size_t iso2utf( unsigned char *buf, unsigned char iso )
{
    size_t res = 0;

    if ( iso & 0x80 ) {
        *buf++ = 0xc0 | (iso >> 6); /* the 110000xx part */
        *buf++ = 0x80 | (iso & 0x3f); /* ... and the 10xxxxxx part. */
        res += 2;
    } else {
        *buf++ = iso; /* a 0xxxxxxx character, untouched. */
        res++;
    }
    *buf = '\0';
    return res;
} /* iso2utf */
```

If you want a complete UTF into UTF-8 encoder, you can try this (I used a different approach, as there can be as much as seven bytes per UTF char ---actually not so much, as currently only 24 or 25 bit codes are used):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int    UTF; /* you can use wchar_t if you prefer */
typedef unsigned char   BYTE;

/* I will assume that UTF string is also zero terminated */
size_t utf_utf8 (BYTE *out, UTF *in)
{
    size_t res = 0;
    for (;*in;in++) {
        UTF c = *in; /* copy the UTF value */
        /* we are constructing the string backwards, so finally
         * we have it properly ordered. */
        size_t  n = 0; /* number of characters for this one */
        BYTE    aux[7], /* buffer to construct the string */
                *p = aux + sizeof aux; /* point one cell past the end */

        static UTF limits[] = { 0x80, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x4, 0x2, 0x01};
        static UTF masks[] = { 0x00, 0xc0, 0xe0, 0xf0, 0xf8, 0xfc, 0xfe};

        for (;c >= limits[n]; c >>= 6) {
            *--p = 0x80 | (c & 0x3f); n++;
        } /* for */
        *--p = masks[n] | c; n++;
        memcpy(out, p, n); out += n; res += n;
    } /* for */
    *out = '\0'; /* terminate string */
    return res;
} /* utf_utf8 */
```

See that the seven bytes per UTF code is hardwired, as it is the fact of UTF codes being 32bit integer.  I don't expect UTF codes to go further past the 32 bit limit, but in that case, both, the UTF `typedef`, and the sizes and contents of the tables `aux`, `limits` and `masks` might be changed accordingly.  There's a maximum limit of 7 or 8 for the number of characters used for the utf-8 encoding also, and it's not specified in the standard in any form how to proceed if the UTF codespace should run out of codes any time, so better not to mesh too much with this.

Answer (score 0):

Useless function parameter: `unsigned char ch`

```
/// In the following bad code, `if(ch < 0x10000)` is never true
int encode(char *buf, unsigned char ch){
    if(ch < 0x80) {
      ...
      return 1;
    if(ch < 0x800) {
      ...
      return 2;
    if(ch < 0x10000) {
```

Sorry, GTG.

Note: Code incorrectly does not detect high and low surrogates.

Comment: I'm confuse now, should it be an `uint32_t`?

Comment: @chux, Sorry, but the comment should be just the opposite, as `(ch < 0x10000)` should **always** be `true`  (for the maximum value of `ch` it's `true`)

Comment: Not @PeteDarrow, You are mistaken in the question you posted in that you want to convert iso-8859-1 characters (one byte codes) into UTF-8 encoding.  As I posted in my answer, the conversion from iso-8859-1 is straightforward, as the codes for iso-8859-1 are the same as the codes for UTF.  So the code must just check if the values are below `0x80` or equal and above.  If you want to write a full UTF encoder, then you have to switch to a type with more than 24-25 bits to be able to fully represent a whole UTF char.

Comment: @Luis Colorado Unicode codespace `0-10FFFF` needs at least 21 bits.  Unclear about the 24-25 of your comment.

Comment: @Luis Colorado Sorry, but `(ch < 0x10000)` is never true because with typical 8-bit `unsigned char`, the code's `if(ch < 0x800) ... return` is always true and code never reaches `if(ch < 0x10000)`.  A smart compiler will optimize out the code after `return 2;`

Comment: @chux, Have you checked what you say?... suppose ch has the value `0xff` (the maximum value an `unsigned char` can have), and then do the comparison.... `(ch < 0x10000)`  ==> `(0xff < 0x10000)` ==> `true`.

Comment: @chux, you are right in the number of characters defined nowadays for UTF version 8.0 (recently published)  but that means you need *at most* 21 bits to represent them now.  however, there are encodings as utf-32 (which encodes utf codes in 32 bits), utf-16 (which uses up to two 16bits to encode one utf char, again 32bit) and utf-8 (which uses up to seven 8bit bytes to encode up to a 32 bit number) As new characters are added to the space, I will have to be expanded to allow them all.  And it continues growing.

Comment: @Luis Colorado  `(ch < 0x10000)` is never executed.  Program never reaches that code.  The function has rerturned before the program ever gets to `if(ch < 0x10000) {`  that is why `ch < 0x10000` is never true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93192/discussion-between-chux-and-luis-colorado).